# Validacion de Radio Button Seleccionado

Tags: jquery, html5, radiobutton

Actualmente estoy validando una serie de radio buttons generados dinamicamente en base a la cantidad de registros existentes en la base de datos.
La validacion la estoy haciendo asi:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
 if ($('input[type=radio]:checked').length === 0) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('DEBE SELECCIONAR AL MENOS UNA VENTA PARA CONTINUAR');
}
e.stopPropagation();
return false;
});
```

La validacion funciona bien, pero el problema es que me muestra x cantidad de alertas por cada registro en la base de datos, es decir, si tengo 5 registros en la BD, se generaran 5 radio buttons y por ende me esta mostrando 5 alertas.

este es mi radio button:

```
<td align="center"><input type="radio" name="sel[]" value="<?=$row['id']?>" id="<?=$row['valor']?>"></td>
```

y el boton que envia el form:

```
<button type="submit" name="Submit" name="boton" id="boton" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light">PAGAR</button>
```

Alguna sugerencia al respecto?

Comment: Y si pones un return después del alert? También tu botón tiene doble atributo name.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner un límite por contador:

```js
var ind = false;
$('form').submit(function(e){
 if (($('input[type=radio]:checked').length === 0) && (ind == false)) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('DEBE SELECCIONAR AL MENOS UNA VENTA PARA CONTINUAR');
  ind = true;
}
e.stopPropagation();
return false;
});
```

Cutre, pero funcional.